# Avoid overwriting the style of a marked cell in Leaflet & Javascript

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geolocation

I have a system where I mark cells with different colours if a geoposition has been obtained within a cell. My issue is that due to the continuous update of geopositions, cells that were marked with one colour can be marked with the other colour as soon as the other colour's condition is true (else if in code). Here is my code

```
if (distance < positionerrortolerance){
    gpsPoint.properties.scanned ="Yes"
    gpsPoint.properties.distance = distance.toFixed(2);
    gpsPoint.properties.positionprecision = radius;
    rectangles.eachLayer(function (layer) {
        if (layer.complementId == k) {
          layer.setStyle({color: "#adff2f"});
        }; 
    });

 } else if (distance >positionerrortolerance && distance <sradius ) {
    gpsPoint.properties.scanned ="No"
    gpsPoint.properties.distance = distance.toFixed(2);
    gpsPoint.properties.positionprecision = radius;
    rectangles.eachLayer(function (layer) {
        if (layer.complementId == k) {
          layer.setStyle({color: "#ff7800"});
        };
    });
};
```

My idea is to assign after `layer.setStyle({color: "#adff2f"});` an attribute = 1 to that layer and then check for `rectangles.attribute != 1` in the `else if (distance >positionerrortolerance && distance <sradius )`I tried some things but they did not work.

Can somebody help? I assume there is an error when I assign the attribute.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it myself by introducing a `scannedId = 0` and then checking it in the `if (layer.complementId == k && layer.scannedId != 1){layer.setStyle({color "#ff7800"})` of the else if condition.